# Please clarify who deleted what (and maybe the basis)

Tags: support

Without taking a stand whether such questions belong on SO or don’t, there are presently 1,020 tagged [vlookup], with a further 65 tagged [gs-vlookup]. One has just been deleted [VLOOKUP not returning the expected value [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847266/vlookup-not-returning-the-expected-value) having been closed under a previous regime as “Too localised”, whose wording in full was:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, visit the help center.

Since the issue turned out to be an incorrect reference for a sheet name the current equivalent would seem to be:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Personally I thought the diagnostic process was worth preserving (possibly in the tag wiki) because it considered five possible causes which between them may cover almost all VLOOKUP errors (and therefore maybe hundreds of SO questions, so far). Hence when I saw the OP had been [closed] I voted to reopen. I did not expect it to be re-opened but certainly did not expect what did happen immediately after, which was deletion by Community. I guess the timing *might* have been coincidence (the OP was 2 years old and had only had 93 views).

My attention to it was drawn by a downvote (I had offered an answer for the sake of completeness – and it had been upvoted). So it seems possible the post’s OP decided on some tidying and countered my +1 in order to be able to delete the question. (I have no problem with that.)
However I am surprised that the post shows “deleted by Community♦” if actually deleted by the OP – and even more surprised that my ‘answer’ (actually, more of an explanation) shows “deleted by owner”.

I managed to keep a copy of the post so I don’t mind the result but would like to understand: what the deleted messages mean in terms of who did what?

Answer (score 29):

The question wasn't deleted by the owner - it *was* deleted by the Community user because your answer got downvoted and made the question [eligible for automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675) by the system.

The "deleted by owner" on your answer is a [long-standing bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120594/deleting-a-question-showed-one-of-the-answer-as-deleted-by-the-owner) due to the fact that you had previously deleted and undeleted it yourself. When the question gets deleted, it deletes all the answers too, but doesn't create a formal deletion event in the history - so the user(s) from the previous deletion event erroneously get used in the statement.